# How to pass props in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I want to pass a data to a function inside `<Home />`.

How to do it? I tried:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  element={(props) => (
    <ContactList
      {...props}
      contacts={contacts}
      getContactId={removeContactHandler}
    />
  )}
/>
```

but the page became blank with no errors but warning as: "Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

Answer (score 0):

If by "props" you mean something like the old `react-router-dom@5` [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), these were removed  in v6. If you want/need to access the older `history`, `location`, and `match` "props" in the current RRD version these were all replaced by React hooks.

| RRDv5 Prop | RRDv6 Hook |
| --- | --- |
| [history](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history) <sup>*</sup> | [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) <sup>*</sup> |
| [location](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location) <sup>*</sup> | [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) <sup>*</sup> |
| [match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match) <sup>*</sup> | [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) |
| [match.params](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match) <sup>*</sup> | [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) <sup>*</sup> |

<sup>*</sup> Commonly used

The `Route` component's [`element`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) prop takes a `React.ReactNode` value, e.g. JSX. Passing a function is invalid. Pass `ContactList` ***as JSX*** to the `element` prop and pass along any additional props like `contacts` and `getContactId` just like normal.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={(
    <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId={removeContactHandler} />
  )}
/>
```

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ContactList = ({ contacts, getContactId }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();

  ...
};
```